# Different slug taxonomy for two different CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, slug

I want to use a one taxonomy of two CPT.
But I want to have different URL.

Like this:

**city** - taxonomy (taxonomy data is used in two CPT)

**people** - CPT

**car** - CPT

I want:

site.com/people/born/LA

site.com/car/place/LA

Thus in the first case I show people born in the LA, and in the second case, cars being in LA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share a taxonomy between multiple custom post types.

You will need to register the taxonomy in your plugin file or theme's functions.php file:

`<?php register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args ); ?>`

[WP Codex: Registering Taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)

When you register your taxonomy you will need to use an array for the $object_type. In this example the taxonomy "city" is being assigned to the "people" and "cars" post types:

```
register_taxonomy(
  'city',
  array( 'people','cars' ),
  array( 'hierarchical' => true,
         'label' => __('City'),
         'query_var' => 'city',
         'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'city' )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `post_type` query string with taxonomy archive URL-

- `http://example.com/city/sydney/?post_type=people`
- `http://example.com/city/sydney/?post_type=car`